# Writing to a new line in a file using Commons IO?

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons

I know that

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myfile.txt, "my string", true);
```

adds 'my string' to the end of myfile.txt, so it looks like

```
previous stringsmy string
```

But is there any way to use Commons IO to write a string to a new line in a file, to change the file to

```
previous strings
my string
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java use `\n` to mark new line so try with:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myfile.txt, "\nmy string", true);
```

Comment: Would put the \n to the end of the string. Otherwise the file starts with an empty row. Like this: `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myfile.txt, "my string\n", true);`

Comment: I agree with your comment, but this was a special case.

Comment: For me, a new file is made every time, a new string is appended...
Any reason for that?

This is my code:
File file=new File("/Users/akshitbhatia/Documents/workspace/SNLP/src/miniProject/output.txt");
for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
String result="\n"+P1+factToken[0]+P2+value+P3+"\t.";
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, result, "UTF-8");
}

Comment: @akshitbhatia   Instead of FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, result, "UTF-8") use FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, result, "UTF-8", true) which will append to existing file.

Answer (score 4):

declare

```
final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and in call, `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(myfile.txt, yourVariable+newLine, true);`

i use a variable , so this was more useful for me

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above mentioned response;

If you doesn't have huge file you can write:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(myfile.txt), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
lines.add("my string");
Files.write(Paths.get(myfile.txt), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

**Generally its good to add new row in the middle of file**

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(myfile.txt)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
lines.add(6, "my string"); // for example
Files.write(Paths.get(myfile.txt), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```